# как запустить секундомер при запуске кода?

Tags: java

всем привет, я совсем новичок в яве, так что не кидайтесь тапками.
есть код `sekundomer`, нашёл этот код на ютубе и он показался мне простым. это код обычного секундомера, вопрос вот в чём, как прописать действие, что бы когда запускался код запускался и отчет времени?
у ютубера он запускается по кнопке, действие он для которой прописал, мне не совсем понятно, как это работает. Объясните пожалуйста !

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class sekundomer implements ActionListener   {

    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        
        int elapsedTime = 0;
        int seconds =0;
        int minutes =0;
        int hours=0;
        boolean started = false;
        String seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
        String minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
        String hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours); 

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                elapsedTime=elapsedTime+1000;
                hours = (elapsedTime/3600000);
                minutes = (elapsedTime/60000)%60;
                seconds = (elapsedTime/1000)%60;
                seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
                minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
                hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
                
                timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
            }
            
            
        });
        
        sekundomer(){
            timeLabel.setText(hours_string+"-"+minutes_string+"-"+seconds_string);
            timeLabel.setBounds(100,100,200,100);
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,35));
            timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
            timeLabel.setOpaque(true);
            timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            
            
            frame.add(timeLabel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(420,420);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    
    void start() {
        timer.start();
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    
    
    
}
```

Comment: возможно ли вообще, прописать `ActionListener` без кнопок??

Answer (score 1):

разобрался! что бы запустить код, нужно было добавить в конец метода `sekundomer` start();